# Php Преобразование подключаемого txt файла в object?

Tags: php, json

Есть файл `test.txt` в котором храниться данные формата (`string`)

```
{"stateFacts":["EntityRoot"],"firstName":"\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f","lastName":"\u041c\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e","middleName":"\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043d\u0430","birthDate":"27.03.1994","gender":"F","trusted":true,"snils":"157-455-794 08","inn":"582462574689","updatedOn":1637579486,"status":"REGISTERED","rIdDoc":28946972,"eTag":"94BF0FFEC005B8673EDABD10C73CD5A278C48594","userId":"1024378747","ctts":[{"stateFacts":["Identifiable"],"id":203780753,"type":"EML","vrfStu":"NOT_VERIFIED","value":"000.27@gmail.com","verifyingValue":"Skudina.27@gmail.com","vrfValStu":"VERIFYING","isCfmCodeExpired":true,"eTag":"E6DE11E50D92FC31187BA2383C7E37D081C2B7B9"},{"stateFacts":["Identifiable"],"id":72481062,"type":"MBT","vrfStu":"VERIFIED","value":"+7(937)0009211","eTag":"E98067A6E14F62277F61720E3C7B6B798B95B84A"}]}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как после получения этого файла в `php`,

```
$full_text = file_get_contents('test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$json = json_decode($full, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

преобразовать его в формат (объекта или моногомерного массива) для последующий работы с ним? Нужно ли его преобразовывать в `json` формат, если будет необходимость в декодировании символов? *новичек в `php`

Comment: чтобы образовать объект, вам нужно распарсить код json функцией `json_decode`. Вот подробнее: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: ```json_encode```(создать из объекта текст) => ```json_decode```(создать из текста объект)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_encode - для кодирования массива в json, а обратно делается json_**decode** (**[документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**). У которого вторым параметром можно написать `true` для перевода в массив.  Если `false`, объекты `JSON` будут возвращены как объекты (`object`). Если `null` (он по умолчанию), объекты `JSON` будут возвращены как ассоциативные массивы (array) или объекты (object) в зависимости от того, установлена ли `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` (последний параметр)

Comment: Если не передавать второй параметр будет не объект а представление как в json, второй параметр заставляет из json объектов делать ассоциативные массивы а не объекты

Comment: Хм... Поменялась логика стало быть... всегда был объект без второго параметра)) .... Возможно и флаг по умолчанию тоже нужный стоИт и поэтому прокатывает (прокатывало).... но это надо смотреть на значения констант, чтобы разобраться))

Comment: Возможно, просто по умолчанию сериализуется "как есть", со вторым параметров в true - объекты в массив а с false как есть(false во втором без третьего и null во втором без третьего дают одинаковый результат - объект будет объектом), до третьего давно не добирался :)

Comment: Посмотрел константы. JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY - 1, а 0 - это JSON_ERROR_NONE (как раз то, что сейчас по умолчанию в пыхе). Очень интересно)) Очень странно. Какой-то костыль. Ну да ладно

Comment: Спасибо, как сделать его удобочитаемым с возможностью получения значений? '$json = json_decode($full, true);
echo $json;
print $json->{'firstName'};' Просто выводит Array

Comment: @BlackStar1991 во-первых не `echo`, а хотя бы `print_r($data)`, а во-вторых, надо вывод обернуть например в тег `<pre>`. представляет собой предварительно отформатированный текст, который должен быть представлен точно так, как написано в HTML-файле  (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)